# Can a global variable be created into sys_generic.c? (OPENBSD)

Tags: c, operating-system, freebsd, openbsd

Here's the question and the problem I'm facing. 
I had a task to create a new kernel function in OpenBSD (into syscalls.master). It is called sys_eventopen(int id). The thing is that into sys_generic.c where the function should be implemented, right into the implementation I need to modify the value of a struct variable like this:

```
struct resource{
    int id=0;
     int is_busy=0;
}res;
```

The thing is that I want to be able to access the res resource into the implementation of the sys_eventopen(). I want to know whether it's possible to declare a global variable into the sys_generic.c so that I can access it into the function or rewrite all the functions so that I could send that variable as a parameter. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think you need to expand a bit on what you are trying to achieve and how. I can imagine several variants of the a `resource` variable that can be used to implement an event, and each variant will have a different behaviour, and need a different implementation. Key part of that is where and how they get modified and whether the ID is one for all processes, per process, or perhaps a kernel only event?

Comment: To clarify: It is important to understand how the events are being used, to give a reasonable answer other than "yes you can" (I'm pretty sure you can have global variables), but that is very likely the wrong solution for what you want to do.

Comment: @MatsPetersson So I have implemented a kind of a simulation for event syncronization in a main.c file into the userland, where I have to call some functions I have written in the kernel (syscalls), like the one I mentioned in my main post "sys_eventopen". The thing is that when I will call eventopen(id) in the main.c file, the eventopen will need to modify the struct file mentioned before, which is not declared anywhere, and I don't think I can declare it in the main.c file. That was my question, if it's possible, where can I declare that struct. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: It's not just about declaring a struct (or declaring a variable of that struct), but also about how you use the calls together, and what you expect to achieve with those calls.

Comment: @MatsPetersson All I need to know is whether I can declare a global variable into the sys_generic.c or not.

Comment: Would be relatively easy to try, wouldn't it?